# Conic section and Bézier curves

Tags: geometry, numerical-methods, conic-sections, curves, bezier-curve

I'd like to prove or disprove the following:

given a compact arc of a conic section $\mathcal{T} \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ such that for any $P \neq Q \in \mathcal{T}$ the tangent vectors $\tau_P, \tau_Q$ aren't parallel, then i can parametrize it using a quadratic Rational Bézier curve.

First of all I can find the three points: the endpoints of the arc and the intersection of the tangent lines at the endpoints (here i use the hypotesis making this intersection nonempty, as a counterexample we can pick a semicircumference). Then I can, without loss of generality, normalize the weights $w_0=w_2=1$. Now, how can I find $w_1$?
I searched on NURBS,Farin, online and even on Stack Exchange. I didn't find a general case (only the one with circular arcs) and moreover it seems that you can only approximate an arc of conic section (why?).

Edit1: I found these slides [https://public.vrac.iastate.edu/~oliver/courses/me625/week11.pdf](https://public.vrac.iastate.edu/%7Eoliver/courses/me625/week11.pdf)
but I don't understand nor the direct approach (because who grants me that of the three equations at least two are linearly independent) nor the geometric one (that one I just don't get it at all).

Comment: I think it’s $w_1$ that you’re trying to find, not $w_2$.

Comment: Yep typo, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this from first principals. From the given conic arc, we can compute the Bézier control points $P_0, P_1, P_2$. And we know we can assume that the weights for the first and last control points are both $1$. So, then, the equation of the Bézier curve is:
$$
C(t) = \frac {(1-t)^2P_0 + 2t(1-t)wP_1 + t^2P_2}
{(1-t)^2+ 2t(1-t)w+ t^2}
$$
We just need to find the middle weight, $w$.

Let $M = \tfrac12(P_0 + P_2)$ be the mid-point of the chord, and let $Q$ be the point where the conic intersects the line segment $MP_1$. After computing $Q$, we define $k = |MQ|/|MP_1|$. Then
$$
Q = (1-k)M + kP_1 = \tfrac12(1-k)P_0 + kP_1 +  \tfrac12(1-k)P_2.
$$
Our strategy is to choose $w$ so that $C(\tfrac12) = Q$. Then the Bézier curve will pass through the points $P_1, Q, P_2$ and it will have the same end tangents as the original conic. A conic is fully determined by three points and two tangents, so if we accept that our rational quadratic curve is a conic, then it must be the same conic as the original one.

But $C(\tfrac12) = Q$ gives us
$$
\frac {\tfrac14P_0 + \tfrac12wP_1 + \tfrac14P_2}
{\tfrac14 + \tfrac12w+ \tfrac14} = 
\tfrac12(1-k)P_0 + kP_1 +  \tfrac12(1-k)P_2.
$$
Equating coefficients of $P_1$. We get
$$
\frac{w}{1+w}= k
$$
And rearranging gives
$$
w = \frac{k}{1-k}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Choose a point $P$ on the conic and a line parameterized by $L(t)= A + tB$. For any given value of $t$, construct a line through $P$ and the line point $L(t)$. Since the conic is a curve of degree 2, this line must intersect the conic in two points. By construction, one of these points is $P$; call the other one $C(t)$. If you work through the algebra, you’ll find that $C(t)$ is a rational quadratic function of $t$.

Alternatively: use the geometry of the given conic to figure out its “shape factor”, $s$. You’ll have to find the intersection of the conic with the line joining its tangent intersection point $P_1$ and the mid-point $M$ of the chord $P_0P_2$. In other words, you have to find $s$ such that this intersection occurs at $(1-s)M + sP_1$. Then compute the weight of the middle control point from this shape factor: $w_1 = s/(1-s)$, as explained in the slides you found.

Comment: I'd like to use the first method since i didn't quite get how to find the shape factor. $A$ and $B$ are the end points of the arc?If so, how comes the line through$L(t)$ and $P$ intesects the conic twice for any given $t$?

Comment: You can use any line you like as long as it doesn’t pass through the point P. To make sure I wasn’t talking nonsense, I worked through an example with P equal to the origin and A and B chosen to give me the line $x=1$, so A=(1,0,0) and B=(0,1,0).

Comment: The second method is easier. The shape factor $s$ is simple enough. The conic has to intersect the line segment $MP_1$ somewhere, right. Call the intersection point $Q$. So we can find $s$ such that $Q = (1-s)M + sP_1$. In fact $s=|MQ|/|MP_1|$.

Comment: Ok I think that for what I need the first method might not do the trick.  I'm trying to parametrize an arc of the conic,  and in some examples the point $C(t)$ is on the conic but not on the arc. I should find suitable $A$ and $B$ ecc... Meanwhile i understood the relationship between $w_1$ and $s$ but i don't know how to find $s$. If I compute it as you suggested, why would it be the shape parameter of the conic?

As an alternative I could also use the method on page 432 of the slides but that's way too unformal: is that a projective map?points in general position? ecc...

Comment: True, the first method will parameterized the entire conic, except that the special point P will be omitted (or it will correspond to $t = \pm\infty$. Then you’ll have to adjust to get the parameter values on your segment to be in the range $[0,1]$.

Comment: ‘Why would it be the shape parameter” — that ratio is the *definition* of the shape parameter.

Comment: In the notes $s$ is found given a Beziér curve $\mathcal{C}(t)$ as the parameter for the convex combination that finds $\mathcal{C}(1/2)$. That $s$ satisfies $w_1=s/(1-s)$. If the shape parameter is that $s$  we are using that $\mathcal{C}(1/2)=Q$ while i don't know this a priori because i am searching for such a  $\mathcal{C}(t)$.